# How do I exclude fields from an embedded document in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a Post document that has embedded tags. Sometimes I display only the title of a post and its tags. In those cases, I use the following query in mongoid:

```
Post.only(:title).find(id)
```

I then send the results of the query as json to the client. Unfortunately, the tag's bson id makes the json much larger than I need it to be. **How do I exclude the "_id" field from the query?**

Here are my models:

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, :type =>  String
  field :body, :type =>  String
  field :tags, :type =>  Array
  embeds_many :tags
end
class Tag
  include Mongoid::Document  
  field :tag, :type =>  String
  field :type, :type =>  String
  embedded_in :post
end
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll need to use Mongoid's `without` method. Something like this should do the trick:

```
Post.without(:_id, :body, "tags._id")
```

Which will return all your post titles only, as well as all their embedded tags and no `_id` fields for either Posts or Tags.

I noticed also that you have `field :tags, :type =>  Array` defined on your Post model - which I believe is redundant. Using `embeds_many` sets that field up for you automatically.

Comment: It works! Thanks for the pointer. I don't know how I overlooked that method!