# Exclude fields from document in mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a Record model with many dynamic attributes. I want to make a request to the model an send the response as JSON to the client. But i want to exclude fields like `_id` and all foreign_keys in this model.

I found an interessting answer how to exclude the values of some keys: [How do I exclude fields from an embedded document in Mongoid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419033/how-do-i-exclude-fields-from-an-embedded-document-in-mongoid), but the keys in the response still exists.

I got:

```
{
 "_id": 1,
 "name": "tom"
}
```

And the `without` method makes:

```
{
  "_id": nil,
 "name": "tom"
}
```

But i want:

```
{
 "name": "tom"
}
```

Is it possible to remove or exclude some keys and the values from the result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want to remove fields from the mongoid document, what you want to do is remove fields from the generated json.
In your controller, do

```
render :json => @model.to_json(:except => :_id)
```

Documentation for the to_json method http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json

Comment: For the generated JSON it is the correct answer. It would be nice if mongoid implement the mongodb functionality what @Dominik mentioned.

Comment: @Mindbreaker That functionality actually exists and you used it when using "without", but when mapping it to your ruby object, your field still exists, and returns nil by default.

Comment: `without` dont do exactly what MongoDB does. I expect a ruby object without that attribute.

Answer (score 1):

taken from the mongodb documentation at: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Exclude Certain Fields from the Result Set
The following example selects documents that match a selection criteria and excludes a set of fields from the resulting documents:

`db.products.find( { qty: { $gt: 25 } }, { _id: 0, qty: 0 } )`
The query returns all the documents from the collection products where qty is greater than 25. The documents in the result set will contain all fields except the _id and qty fields, as in the following:

```
{ "item" : "pencil", "type" : "no.2" }
{ "item" : "bottle", "type" : "blue" }
{ "item" : "paper" }
```

i suppose mongoid is setting the _id attribute to nil since mongoid models have a defined set of attributes (even if they are dynamic, _id, _type etc are defined). maybe you can try it with the mongodb driver.

but i think RedXVII answer is the more practical way to go